# WooCommerce remove shipping fields first and last name

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, field, checkout

I've got these code to unset required fileds en check out car:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_fields', 'shipping_remove_fields' );`
function shipping_remove_fields( $fields )`
{
unset( $fields[ 'shipping_last_name' ][ 'required' ] );
unset( $fields[ 'shipping_first_name' ][ 'required' ] );
return $fields; 
}
```

How can i hide fields on shipping form?

Hide fielsd name surname etc.. on shippment.

Comment: Your question is unclear, try to use Google Translate. Also, does your code work? There are no "fields on shipment", but shipping fields.

Comment: I've used these code ( from  stack over flow )and  worked. Your answer is great and worked successful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To hide checkout shipping first and last name fields use:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_fields', 'shipping_remove_fields' );
function shipping_remove_fields( $fields )
{
    unset( $fields[ 'shipping_last_name' ] );
    unset( $fields[ 'shipping_first_name' ] );
    return $fields; 
}
```

---

To hide checkout shipping fields entire section, just use:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_needs_shipping_address', '__return_false');
```